Issues with Implementing Sign-out in JavaScript Application Using ASP.NET Core Identity and OpenIddict
I'm currently working on a web application using ASP.NET Core for the backend with Identity and OpenIddict for authentication, and Next.js for the frontend with Next Auth v5. I'm facing issues with implementing the sign-out functionality correctly.
On the server side, I have the following setup for the logout action:
[Authorize]
[ActionName(nameof(Logout)), HttpPost("~/connect/logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutPost()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return SignOut(
        authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        properties: new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/"
        });
}

And on the client side (Next.js with Next Auth v5), I'm attempting to manually trigger the sign-out process by sending a POST request to the logout endpoint:
import { signIn, signOut, auth } from "@/lib/auth"
import { Button } from "./ui/button"
const logOut = async () => {
  try {
    const session = await auth();
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('token ', session?.accessToken as string);

    const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7277/connect/logout", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: params
    });
    console.log(params);
    // Log the response body    
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to log out');
    }
    await signOut();
    // Perform client-side sign-out if needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error logging out:', error);
    throw error;
  }

};

However, the sign-out process is not successful. I can't invoke the LogoutPost action, and there are no error messages returned. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm handling the access token or the server-side logout process.
What could I be missing here?
